# The Component menu (backend) contains a Categories entry pointing to com_weblink which doesn't exist

Tags: joomla-3.4

So it displays a error:

> Error loading component: com_weblinks, Component not found.

How can I suppress this menu entry (I don't need Web Links) ?

It's a site migrated from a 2.5 one, which was the migration of a 1.5 one.

I've tried installing/uninstalling the Web Links Manager from JED but that didn't work. The Components -> Categories entry is always here.

The entry points to index.php?option=com_categories&extension=com_weblinks. This is the same as the sub-menu of Component-> Weblinks -> Categories when the Weblinks Manager is installed. Just like if this sub-menu entry became a main menu entry and hence cannot be uninstalled...

NB : in the extensions table, the only occurrence of com_categories is:

```
com_categories: (6, 'com_categories', 'component', 'com_categories', '', 1, 1, 1, 1, '{"name":"com_categories","type":"component","creationDate":"December 2007","author":"Joomla! Project","copyright":"(C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.","authorEmail":"admin@joomla.org","authorUrl":"www.joomla.org","versio‌​n":"3.0.0","description":"COM_CATEGORIES_XML_DESCRIPTION","group":""}', '', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0)
```

Doesn't seem to correspond to my menu entry...

Any idea anybody ?

Comment: Could you please format your question so it's a little bit more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your migration from J2.5 to J3 included weblink records even when it is not included now.

Even, if you install and uninstall weblink extension, it does not clean these records.

I would manually locate category weblink records (#__categories, extension=com_weblinks) and remove them.

Comment: The menu item is in the #__menu table. Check that as well.

Comment: There was nothing bad in #__categories. The bad entry was in the #__menu table. Deleted it and now everything is fine. Many thanks for your help !